# Javax Mail getMesseges and Search returns 0 while should not

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

This is the code i use:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(new Properties(), null);
store = session.getStore("pop3s");
store.connect(host, username, password);
inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
message=inbox.getMessages();
System.out.println(message==null ? "null" : message.length);
final Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
calender.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
SearchTerm term = new SearchTerm() {
    public boolean match(Message message) {
        try {
            if (message.getSentDate().getTime()>calender.getTime().getTime()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
};
message = inbox.search(term);
System.out.println(message==null ? "null" : message.length);
```

I also tried :

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(new Properties(), null);
store = session.getStore("pop3s");
store.connect(host, username, password);
inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
ReceivedDateTerm term  = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT,cal.getTime());
message = inbox.search(term);
System.out.println(message==null ? "null" : message.length);
```

But all i get is 0 messeges while when i log in with GMail manually i do see relevant messeges, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you try to send a new mail and try with your application..

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the host? i use pop.gmail.com perhaps it has something to do with it?